# Minimal JFace application making use of FilteredTree

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application I have a JFace dialog making use of FilteredTree, which depends on the running PlatformUI.

Now I want to add a `main` method to the dialog class, so I can start this dialog for testing purpose quickly. But I get an exception from within the FilteredTree ctor:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/e4/core/di/InjectionException
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning(PlatformUI.java:114)
at org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(AbstractUIPlugin.java:669)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree.<clinit>(FilteredTree.java:196)
at my.MyDialog.createDialogArea(MyDialog.java:361)
```

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a `main` method. Eclipse has a huge amount of initialization that must be done before plug-in code can be run and this requires that the normal Eclipse main method is used.